# Compile Fortran to mex on Mac

Tags: macos, matlab, fortran

I have been forced to return to an old bugbear lately: compiling a fortran script to run under Matlab on Mac. I have managed to compile the example c file to mex but the Fortran file refuses unless I use -c and the object of my desire, kt3d.for, throws up a whole list of fun but all linked to the same error (I guess).

I'm running Matlab R2011b on OSX 10.7.5 with XCode 4.6.1.

I've patched Matlab according http://www.mathworks.se/support/solutions/en/data/1-FR6LXJ/

Got a Fortran compiler running according to https://sites.google.com/site/dwhipp/tutorials/mac_compilers

I altered the mex file to call bash rather than sh but still no joy. Getting tired of having to boot up my old XP machine every time I want to run a kriging package so I would really like to compile these things for OSX.

Below is the error, it looks like an architecture issue but I cant figure out how to fix it.

```
>> mex kt3d.for
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_chknam_", referenced from:
      _readparm_ in kt3d.o
  "_cova3_", referenced from:
      _kt3d_ in kt3d.o
  "_ktsol_", referenced from:
      _kt3d_ in kt3d.o
  "_mexfunction_", referenced from:
     -exported_symbol[s_list] command line option
  "_picksup_", referenced from:
      _kt3d_ in kt3d.o
  "_setrot_", referenced from:
      _kt3d_ in kt3d.o
  "_setsupr_", referenced from:
      _kt3d_ in kt3d.o
  "_srchsupr_", referenced from:
      _kt3d_ in kt3d.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

    mex: link of ' "kt3d.mexmaci64"' failed.

Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe those symbols are found in [GSLIB](http://scrf.stanford.edu/resources.software.gslib.php). Assuming you have this installed and somewhere that your compiler can find it, you may need to add something like "`-lgslib`" to your mex command to get it to link the library for you.

Comment: I'm compiling the kt3d.for script which is in the GSLIB package but it seems as if it cant find the other functions. Is this this a linking error?

Comment: OK, went back to the GSLIB web page and reread the compilation instructions and tried that on gslib2. I'm lost. I adjusted gslib_compile.bat to a sh and ran that. This did not seem to give the desired result. Would show output here but the mini-Markdown `code`doesn't seem to produce a readable text. Basically it cant find the files which seems not unreasonable as the subfolders they are supposed to exist in don't exist, the executables seem to be located directly under /bin

Comment: I can't say I've ever worked with GSLIB, so if you could edit your question to add in your code, that would be good. Also, I noticed that `_mexfunction_` is among the missing symbols, which suggests to me that the file you're compiling is not in fact a MATLAB MEX extension. Does it actually have a function called mexFunction? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexfunction.html

Comment: Not yet, no. But then that's what I'm trying to make. It would seem that until I sort out the compilation of the internal GSLIB libraries the fortran compiler and mex compiler wont work anyway. The GISLIB documentation seems a little outdated (not sure when anybody last used a diskette). It looks like I am going to have to go through the makefile for each library component and check its validity. Not a fun task if you know what you are doing, considerably worse if, like me, you know next to nothing about compiling etc.

Comment: Where did you get the code you're trying to compile? I just downloaded gslib and grep'd through it a bit. There is no indication that any MATLAB extension code is in this library. You can't just throw random libraries at MEX and expect it to eat them, it only accepts code specifically written for it.

Comment: Hmm, then GLSIB stuff has been compiled on Windows to mex. As I understood it, gfortran (if that is what is installed) is called to compile executables that are wrapped for Matlab to run as mex files. But I'm probably wrong.

Comment: MATLAB mex code needs to have a special function (called `mexFunction`) written in C or Fortran. This is the function that MATLAB runs when you use the compiled mex library. Neither gfortran or MATLAB's mex utility will write it for you, so you absolutely need to have it. If you're using gslib inside of MATLAB, someone somewhere has written this for you, so you should try to find it. Otherwise, you'll have to write it yourself, which may or may not be fun for you.

Comment: OK, I'll try to get in touch with the gut who did the XP compilation. Thanks for the help.